# Vs code regex replace part of string and keep other

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code

I need quick help with regex I have

```
'http://127.0.0.1:5000/register'
```

and want to replace it with

```
`${process.env.API_URL}/register`
```

doing this regex:

```
'http://127.0.0.1:5000/.*'
```

takes the whole thing

Comment: If the string is fixed, what is the point of using regex?

Comment: what do you mean by fixed?

Comment: You don't need `.*`. Just replace `http://127.0.0.1:5000/` with `${process.env.API_URL}/`

Comment: one string starts with ' and other starts with `

Comment: not the same type in js

Comment: Use a capture group to capture the variable part that matches `.*` and copy it to the replacement.

Answer (score 3):

Use a capture group to copy the part after `/`

Find: `'http://127.0.0.1:5000/(.*)'`

Replace: `` `${process.env.API_URL}/$1` ``